# How did I end up with a git empty changelist that deletes one of its parents?

Tags: git

Twice in the last two days, I have had non-technical git users armed with SourceTree do merges that contained no changes, but discarded all the changes on the non-master parent codeline. We were able to repair these through judicious use of `git cherry-pick` and `git revert -m`, but I don't understand what happened there, nor how to advise them to avoid this happening in future. Any git gurus have any ideas?

Comment: What does "discarded all the changes" mean?  Did existing commits on a branch disappear in some sense?

Comment: Exactly. The changes that occurred in master are there, the changes that occurred in the other "branch" (actually on another developer's local master & pushed to the central remote) are gonezors. The changes are visible in the history, but none of the actual file edits are there.

Comment: What's the state of the repo?  Is there a detached head?  A bunch of uncommitted/unstaged changes?

Comment: This sounds like a "merge with `ours` strategy", i.e., merge some branch but ignore all the changes in it.  I know nothing about SourceTree, but if it's a GUI maybe there's some "ignore theirs, use ours" box that gets checked somehow.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Aside from the missing changes, the repo is in fine state -- perfectly valid HEAD pointer that points to the questionable merge.

Comment: @torek That sounds like a promising lead. You should probably propose it as an actual answer rather than a comment, so if it turns out to be correct I can flag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was an error on the part of the non-technical user. He was getting conflicts on the pull, then throwing them away and committing it (!).